# Onsen - UI/HTML5 with React Native

Tags: html, react-native, onsen-ui

Is there a way to use Onsen-UI as a UI front end, or just regular HTML5, with React Native?

I know React Native was meant to be used alongside React.js, but there's two reasons why I'd like to use a different front end framework like Onsen or Ionic. The first being the fact that I don't want to learn a new framework right now, I don't have the time. And second, I have existing Cordova based apps built with Onsen which I'd like to move over onto React Native.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Onsen UI provides React components. Some of them are very similar to the React Native components.

Here are the docs for the Onsen UI React components: https://onsen.io/v2/docs/react/navigator.html

Onsen UI is a web library for Cordova. so it can't be used to render into Native components. Of course, you can use Onsen UI with React inside a WebView in a native app.